# Why Aren't Streamlit and Playwright Playing Nicely Together (Solving NotImplementedError)?

Tags: python, playwright, streamlit

I’m trying to use Playwright with streamlit on Windows using Python, and I keep getting a NotImplementedError.   Here’s a simple Streamlit app, using the hello-world example from playwright’s Python documentation:

```
import streamlit as st
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

st.write(“Starting the test…”)

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(http://playwright.dev)
    st.write((page.title())
    browser.close()
```

And here’s the error message:

```
NotImplementedError
Traceback:
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py”, line 557, in _run_script
exec(code, module.dict)
File “app.py”, line 6, in 
with sync_playwright() as p:
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api_context_manager.py”, line 87, in enter
dispatcher_fiber.switch()
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api_context_manager.py”, line 67, in greenlet_main
self._loop.run_until_complete(self._connection.run_as_sync()) this
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py”, line 616, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_connection.py”, line 210, in run_as_sync
await self.run()
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_connection.py”, line 219, in run
await self._transport.connect()
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_transport.py”, line 139, in connect
raise exc
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_transport.py”, line 127, in connect
self._proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py”, line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py”, line 1630, in subprocess_exec
transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
File “c:\users\aschneiderman\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py”, line 491, in _make_subprocess_transport
raise NotImplementedError
```

I did some googling and couldn’t find anything.  Any thoughts on how to diagnose what’s going wrong and how to fix it?